# Sign with google services, why should I use the credentials created for my backend?

Tags: android, authentication, oauth

On this page (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) under the subtitle, "**Get your backend server's OAuth 2.0 client ID**", it says:

> If your app authenticates with a backend server or accesses Google
>   APIs from your backend server, you must get the OAuth 2.0 client ID
>   that was created for your server.

But I can't see why this is so important?  If I made some credentials associated with the SHA1 of my android device, I would still be able to get the token and pass it to my backend, so why is it so important I use the credentials created for my backend?

**Update** I think I misread the documentation.  I don't think it ever wanted me to use the client id created for my backend in my device, merely that a separate id had to be created for my backend, as the credentials created for Android/iOS don't have a client secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Authenticate with a backend server**  you can see this warning:

> Do not accept plain user IDs, such as those you can get with the GoogleSignInAccount.getId() method, on your backend server. A modified client application can send arbitrary user IDs to your server to impersonate users, so you must instead use verifiable ID tokens to securely get the user IDs of signed-in users on the server side.

So if you want to authenticate user with backend you'll need to get call getIdToken() on android, send it to server, verify received token on server (here you need to check client id)
Why it is important? In this same chapter you can read:

> The value of aud in the ID token is equal to one of your app's client
>   IDs. This check is necessary to prevent ID tokens issued to a
>   malicious app being used to access data about the same user on your
>   app's backend server.

For authentication purposes you can use ClientId from credentials for Android. 
Web credential is required if you want to use server side access to API's on behalf of user. In that case you'll need web credential, because it contains in addition clientSecret, witch is necessary to exchange received token to access and refresh tokens.

Comment: But I would still be able to call `getIdToken` on the response from google, regardless of whether I used credentials created for my device or the credentials created for my backend.

Comment: ok, now I get your issue. So for authentication only there's no difference. You can use ClientId of android credential. But if you want to use server side access to API's on behalf of user then you'll need web credential, because it contains in addition clientSecret, witch is necessary to exchange received token to access and refresh tokens.

Comment: Yeah ok, I think I totally misread the documentation.  I read it like my device would have to use the same client id as was created for my backend, which I didn't think made sense.  If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm glad that everything is clear now.